# Realm Java query on two columns of nested object

Tags: java, android, realm

Here is my Structure:

```
class Class1 {
  String name; 
  RealmList<Class2> objects;
}

class Class2{
  String field1;
  String field2;
  String field3;
}
```

What I want to do is query all the `Class1` object where `Class2.field1 in ["someValue1"]` and `Class2.field2 = "someValue2"` but unable to do so.

Here is my query:

`realm.where(Class1.class).in("objects.field1",getField1Array()).equalTo("objects.field2", getField2()).findAll()`

Above query does `or` operation on `field1` and `field2` where as what i want is `and` operation.

Is it possible to query by 2 columns of nested object? if yes than how?

Example:

```
{
    "class1": [
        {
            "name": "JOHN",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "field1": "COMPLETE",
                    "field2": "f2"
                },
                {
                    "field1": "HOLD",
                    "field2": "f3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "JOHN",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "field1": "COMPLETE",
                    "field2": "f1"
                },
                {
                    "field1": "HOLD",
                    "field2": "f3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this query

```
realm.where(Class1.class).in("objects.field1",["COMPLETE", "INPROGESS"]).equalTo("objects.field2", "f3").findAll()
```

I expect query to return empty list, but I received both the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
realm.where(Class1.class)
  .in("objects.field1",["COMPLETE", "INPROGESS"])
  .findAll()
  .equalTo("objects.field2", "f3")
  .findAll()
```

---

If that doesn't work, then what you need to do is set up a bi-directional relationship, and invert the query to be based on `Class2` instead of `Class1`.

Comment: Sorry, Its not working for me. I think what above query is doing is- It gets all the objects where `objects.field1` is either `"COMPLETE"` or `"INPROGESS"`
and then makes another query to check `objects.field2` equals f3.
This will give all the objects as first query will return 2 Objects and then second query will check for `objects.field2 = f3` which is also true. so it will return both the objects.
What I wanted to do is get all the `Class1` objects where in each `Class2` object `objects.field1 in "COMPLETE", "INPROGESS"` and `"objects.field2" = "f3"`. i.e. empty list in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
I think the problem is, Realm applies query on a List as a whole. where as what I wanted is query on each list items. To make it more clear, In a example given in link. I want to Find Person/s who has Red dog with name Fido. I think that's not possible with the given way of query. Am I right? or I am missing something.

Comment: so, The query would look like this.
`RealmResults<Person> r2 = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("dogs.name", "Fido").findAll().where().equalTo("dogs.color", "Red").findAll();`
This will give me `U1` where as What I want is empty list.